# Por que a função require_once funciona no localhost mas não funciona no servidor?

Tags: php, require

Prezados tenho um framework que acessa dados de outros servidores, programei todo sistema em localhost, na minha máquina. Porém, ao jogar para o servidor não funciona a chamada externa de páginas, por exemplo:

```
require_once("http://meusite.com.br/pagina.php");
```

Já setei *allow_url_include* = On e *allow_url_fopen* = On, porém não funciona.

**Aparecem os erros:**
Warning: require_once('http://meusite.com.br/pagina.php'): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/pagina.php on line 231 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://meusite.com.br/pagina.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/i9/pagina on line 231

Detalhe: Embora eu queria incluir páginas de outros servidores, o servidor que me refiro "meusite.com.br" é o próprio servidor onde está a "pagina.php". Será que pode ser esse o problema? Que ao invés de usar o require_once através de url, eu sou forçado a user o caminho *DIR*?

Será que precisarei usar file_gets_content()?

Comment: Deu timeout no servidor de produção.

Comment: Inclusive o file_gets_content() dá timeout, o que será, que variável devo setar no servidor?

Comment: Você está tentando incluir uma página de dentro do mesmo servidor? Ou você está em outro?

Comment: Isso, dentro do mesmo servidor!

Comment: Tente usar isso:
`<?php
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php'); 
?>`

Comment: @KhaosDoctor existe alguma propriedade que bloquei isso de fazer qualquer tipo de referência ao próprio servidor? Pois dei um cURL em um site externo e funcionou, e inclusive do meu localhost para o servidor de produção ele responde com as páginas. Mas quando joguei pra ele mesmo não funciona mais.

Comment: Tem muita coisa que pode estar causando o problema, mas nenhuma delas está relacionada ao seu código ou a configuração do PHP. A mensagem de erro informa claramente que a requisição falhou por timeout, portanto, tem algo bloqueando a conexão, é só você pegar um papel e caneta e escrever toda a rota que seu servidor terá que fazer pra se conectar corretamente a essa URL, o erro vai estar em um dos pontos. O mais comum é que algum firewall esteja bloqueando a conexão, inclusive, se você usa CloudFlare no domínio informado no include, é bem provável que seja o motivo do problema.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira eu também acho que esse é o problema vou verificar.

Comment: Ok, e mais uma coisinha. Se não tiver um motivo bem razoável pra você estar usando include via URL (já que como você disse, o tal arquivo a ser incluído está no mesmo servidor), é melhor usar o método convencional por diretório. O motivo é bem simples e obvio. Mas... entretanto todavia contudo, se você setou pro seu servidor responder ao domínio de forma interna (sem precisar resolver os DNS), já diminui um pouco o problema.

Comment: Pessoal, o problema agora é que ao passar parâmetros no require_once (mesmo usando o diretório local) dá erro. "require_once(__ROOT__."/i9tax_new/teste.php?group=".$_GET['group']."&idUsuario=".$_SESSION['i9_usuario']);" Não é permitido passar parâmetros? Localmente eu consegui fazer isso em um servidor PHP (XAMPP WINDOWS) mas no servidor de produção que é LINUX não consigo, algum parâmetro para ajustar?

Comment: Warning: require_once(/var/www/i9tax_new/teste.php?group=731db9563f89bd76f55f9619b61d3da4&idUsuario=400379d4eaa6ec24826dd44cd5cf65a3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/i9/principal.php on line 238 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/i9tax_new/teste.php?group=731db9563f89bd76f55f9619b61d3da4&idUsuario=400379d4eaa6ec24826dd44cd5cf65a3' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/i9/principal.php on line 238

Comment: `require_once` com parâmetros? Reestruture seu código para que teste.php só tenha funções/classes, `require_once` nesse arquivo sem parâmetro, e em qualquer lugar do seu código chame as funções/classes.

Comment: Verdade @AndréLFSBacci ótima ideia, obrigado! Não havia pensado nisso, que tosco kk, é que eu migrei uma plataforma para outra aí muitos conceitos tentei manter e nem me liguei na orientação a objetos.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, consegui! Vou fazer o seguinte: 1 - colocar uma flag nos módulos da plataforma para saber se são módulos internos (do próprio servidor) ou se são módulos de servidor de terceiros (outros programadores outros servidores), se for interno ele usa o _ROOT_ se for externo ele usa o require_once  no servidor do endereço do terceiro.

Comment: Pessoal, tenho um problema semelhante, dessa vez com relação a simulação de uma página ".html", eu queria usar a função para buscar o conteúdo da página file_get_contents("http://meusite.com.br/pagina.html") que está no meu próprio servidor, porém não quero só o código da página quero que ela seja "processada pelo file_get_contents" que simula a abertura a página por um usuário externo, ou seja a página "pegarconteudo.php" está no mesmo servidor que "pagina.html" e ocorre o mesmo erro de time_out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, a maioria dos problemas com time_out se não forem devido configurações do seu servidor apache, pode ser como no meu caso.

Consegui solucionar o problema, a questão é que eu estava apontando a função file_gets_content() para o próprio servidor que rodo a aplicação que desejo. Ou seja, ao invés de usar "localhost" usei "http://meusite.com.br" gerando um certo tipo de looping no servidor.

Problema resolvido!